# jquery, run form

Tags: jquery

how to activate the button. If the condition is true, I want to send data through a method (POST).

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){                   
    var count = 0;
    if(count == 2)
    {
        //run form
    }
});
</script>
</head>                                                                 
<body>
<form action = "" method = "post">
<input type = "text" name = "name" />
<input type = "submit" id = "ok"/>
</form>
```

Comment: hi, you wanna submit form or just want to trigger button click?

Comment: then use jquery .submit event. It will allow you to call custom method before submitting form and you can even cancel form submitting inside that method by returning false or by calling event.preventDefault()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){                   
    var count = 0;
    if(count == 2)
    {
        $("myform").submit(function(e){
             //This function is called before form is posted
             if(mycondition == true)
                return true;   //that will post the form
             else
                 return false; // that will stop posting form 

               //Here you can also change values of input fields and also do  
               // validation on them.
               // instead of return false you can also use e.preventDefault() 
               //  that will stop this event to do what it usually does that
                // is submit the form.
           }).trigger("submit"); //if you want it to submit immediatly
        }
    });
```

**OR if you dont wanna use form id then**

```
 $(document).ready(function(){                   
        var count = 0;
        if(count == 2)
        {
            $("body form").find(":input[type=submit][id=ok]").trigger("click");
        }
    });

    <form action = ""  method = "post">
    <input type = "text" name = "name" />
    <input type = "submit" id = "ok"/>
    </form>
```

Comment: If you are using id selector then no need for any additional selectors to be combined.

Comment: just for filtering more precisely since amateurs usually assign same id to more than one element.

Comment: Its not valid to assign same id to more than one element.

Comment: well it is not valid but it is possible and browser wont complain about that.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$("#ok").trigger("click");
```

Comment: I think this is an elegant solution. Is there any difference compared to $("myform").submit(); ?

Comment: yup, The submit event is sent to an element when the user is attempting to submit a form. It can only be attached to <form> elements. Its a shortcut for $("#myform").trigger("submit");. Where as click event can be binded to any element in the DOM.